# Can't Find Eclipse Project Folder in Project Location

Tags: eclipse

Recently all of my projects in my Eclipse's package explorer have disappeared (but can still be found in the original source folder). However whenever I try to make a new project, the file cannot be found in the location speicfied by Eclipse.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ^ I have indeed but the problem persists.

Comment: If incase re-importing not work you can have a look your project directory whether there is a .project file. Eclipse need this file to detect a directory as an eclipse project